# Passing a path to a python script in OS X

Tags: python

I have a bunch of media files, and I have [a script](https://github.com/mdhiggins/sickbeard_mp4_automator/blob/master/README.md) that will automatically encode and rename them for me

Each file is in its own directory and both the directory and the file have spaces in their name. Such as

```
./Movie, The (2016)/Movie, The (2016).mkv
```

If I run the script like this it works fine

```
manual.py ./Movie, \ The \ (2016)/Movie.....
```

I managed to copy a command from various examples using find and xargs 
Find *.mkv then pass the result to manual.py

The problem is that the Python script doesn't like spaces. Is there a way to:

- Use find to locate the particular extensions
- pass the file and folder to the python script
- keep the spaces as "\ "

Comment: You can quote arguments with spaces on the command line: `python myscript.py "this has spaces"`

Comment: Great!! yes that works but is there a simple one-line command to search for *.mkv, then run manual.py "/path to file/filename" so that it will execute the script for all the found files?